# Impala query results export to csv file only if it fetches any row

Tags: shell, unix, hadoop, impala

I want to export query results from Impala to a csv file through UNIX shell script. I want to write to csv only if the query returns any rows. If it doesn't return any row, the code should send mail saying no records found. If the impala query returns any row, it should write to a csv file.

My current script can export results to csv. But when no rows are fetched, a blank csv gets generated.

```
impala_connection="impala-shell -k --ssl -i 1.1.1.1"

mail_id="abc@def.com"
status="Fail"

query="select process_id, batch_id, job_name, status_cd from table_name where status_cd=\"$status\";"

$impala_shell -B -q "$query" -o /local/job_failures.csv '--output_delimiter=,'
```

Comment: `if ! [ -s $file ] ; then /bin/rm $file ; echo "no data from query" | mail user@server; fi` would be the way to deal with this in a shell script. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, Shelter. Could you please tell me what -s denote here?

Comment: `-s` ~ "size", the statment means, "if file doesn't have a size (zero is not a size in this context), then delete the zero file and send an email". Good luck.